# differences between debug key and hash key registered for Facebook Development

Tags: java, android, facebook, key

I cloned a github project in java [this](https://github.com/TakefiveInteractive/Ledger-Android/), and its Using Facebook SDK for Android with ProGuard. The build requirements is **debug** key registered for Facebook Development. the developer said that You will need to specify the location of your debug key in `local.properties`:
`keys.ledgerGroupDebug=XXX \\what is this and how to get it?
 keys.ledgerGroupDebug.password=XXX \\what is this and how to get it?`

I google it find hash key, nothing about debug key, i got confuse is there are a differences between debug key and hash key?

Comment: I think you need to specify your keystore location and password

Comment: There is two different key Debug hask key and Release hash key, If you generate hashkey using local keystore file that is DebugHashKey. If you generate hashkey using jks file that is ReleaseHashKey